# Separate numbers with comma n fields in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code. In the text input field how can I make it so that a comma is appropriately added to the number? For example, instead of it saying “1000” make it say “1,000”. Or as another example, if I inputted “1000000” make it say “1,000,000”. Unfortunately JS is not my strong side.
Thank you in advance!

```
  function priceCalculation(a){
           if(a <= 10000){
             return 0.00099;
           }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
             return 0.00095;
           }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
             return 0.00089;
           }else if(a >= 50001 && a <= 100000 ){
             return 0.00075;
           }else{
             return 0.00075;
           }
        }

        $('#likecount').keyup(function(){
          var price = priceCalculation($(this).val());
          console.log(price)
          var total = $(this).val() * price;
          $('#output').text(total.toFixed(2));
        }); 



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <input type="text" id="likecount" />
        <p style="padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Your Cost: <b><span> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b></p>
```

Screenshot where I need the commas:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: @AndreFeijo nope, cause I need the solution for the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the use of `ECMAScript 6`'s number formatting ([see here](http://es6-features.org/#NumberFormatting)) you can do it like:

**UPDATED SCRIPT** :

```js
function priceCalculation(a){
    if(a <= 10000){
        return 0.00099;
    }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
        return 0.00095;
    }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
        return 0.00089;
    }else if(a >= 50001 && a <= 100000 ){
        return 0.00075;
    }else{
        return 0.00075;
    }
}

// number format set to en-US e.g (from 1500 to 1,500)
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

$('#likecount').keyup(function(e){
    // if a '.' is pressed
 if($(this).val().endsWith('.')) {
     return;
    }

    // if input value is empty then assign '0' else the original value
    var inputVal = $(this).val() === ''?'0':$(this).val();
  
    // replace the ',' to '' so we won't get a NaN result
    // on arithmetic operations
    inputVal = parseFloat(inputVal.replace(/[$|,]/g, ''));
    var price = priceCalculation(parseInt(inputVal));
    var total = inputVal * price;
    var formatted = numFormat.format(inputVal) // set format to input
    $(this).val(formatted); // display the formatted input back
    $('#output').text(numFormat.format(total)); // display the total price
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="likecount" />
        <p style="padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Your Cost: <b><span> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b></p>
```

Comment: Great Solution! But I need the separator for the input field. Could you, please, explain where should I type the code in my case (commas for the input fields like on the screenshot)? Thank you in advance

Comment: oh... wait there still a bug

Comment: @Morgari recheck the demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function toLocaleString(), it will make sure the final number will look like you want:

```js
console.log((1000000).toLocaleString())
console.log((123456.321).toLocaleString())
console.log((123.3212).toLocaleString())
console.log((1234.56).toLocaleString())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, my JS knowledge is extremely bad. Where should I type this code?

Comment: `$('#output').text(total.toLocaleString()) `

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed and my numbers in the field are still without commas.

Comment: But I noticed that it has changed in the "Price" value. But I need the commas here (screenshot in the tread attached)

Comment: I love your solution. Could you, please, explain where should I type the code in my case (commas for the text fields like on the screenshot)? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Morgari, it will be nice if you vote a good answer. the voting system is here exactly for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var profits=2489.8237 profits.toFixed(3) //returns 2489.824 (round up) profits.toFixed(2) //returns 2489.82 profits.toFixed(7) //returns 2489.8237000 (padding)
```

Then you can add the sign of '$'.

If you require ',' for thousand you can use:

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){ var n = this, c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, d = d == undefined ? "." : d, t = t == undefined ? "," : t, s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))), j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0; return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : ""); };
```

And use it with:

```
(123456789.12345).formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
```

If you're always going to use '.' and ',', you can leave them off your method call, and the method will default them for you.

```
(123456789.12345).formatMoney(2);
```

If your culture has the two symbols flipped (i.e. Europeans), just paste over the following two lines in the formatMoneymethod:

```
d = d == undefined ? "," : d, t = t == undefined ? "." : t,
```

Comment: Thank you so much @javarbtech. Unfortunately, my JS knowledge is extremely bad. Where should I type this code?

Comment: NP... Accept if it helps you